# Should OAuth2 with grant_type "password" work for "High Volume Customer Portal" users?

Tags: oauth2, authentication

I am using the "/services/oauth2/token" end point with grant_type "password" (and with client_id, client_secret, username, password) from JavaScript code. With "IP Restrictions" set to "Relax IP restrictions" in the "Connected App" definition, this allows me to obtain an access_token by just supplying the username and password (no security token) which is good.

However, while this code works for a "System Administrator" profile user ("Salesforce" license), the same code does not work for a "High Volume Customer Portal" profile user ("High Volume Customer Portal" license); the latter profile has "API Enabled" checked. The error returned in that case is:

```
{"error_description":"expired access/refresh token","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

Is this a license type issue or have I just got some other inconsistency between the two users that is causing the problem?

(There is a mention of username/password in a comment in [OAuth for Portal Users](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html) but it is rather brief.)

Comment: Have you tried with a Customer Community License user?  It's the same security model and HVCP but it has some subtle differences, this might be one of them?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; as my org doesn't have that license listed I can't quickly test your suggestion. Do you have a link you could share that that describes the differences?

Comment: Why are you using username/password for HVCP users, rather than web server or user agent?

Comment: The application is AngularJS packaged by PhoneGap Build and running inside iOS. So ideally no UI (login page etc) would come from the server: the server would just provide REST/JSON APIs (services). Once you have a session ID this all works well: the problem is how to get a session ID from JavaScript and OAuth username/password looked like one way. Is there a better way? Or is it just going to be necessary to serve the login etc pages from the server as HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OAuth username-password for Portal/Communities users is not possible.

The usual approach to authenticating users to Salesforce in a mobile app is to pop up a webview with the OAuth user agent login URL and watch for the final redirect to the 'success' URL. [I got this working with the PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin a while ago](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/phonegap.html); things have changed a lot in PhoneGap since then, but that shows the general approach.

On the other hand, if you REALLY want to do username/password, you can do [SOAP login](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) against the portal using [LoginScopeHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_loginscopeheader.htm).

In general, the web-based login is preferred, since it will handle SSO from enterprise identity providers, Facebook, Google etc.

Comment: Thanks. I take the point about allowing the sign-on to be varied at the server-side and am taking that approach now. Ugly in some ways though. Can you add a big "No" to your answer relating to the original question to perhaps save other people spending time trying to make it work?

Comment: Just went back and looked at the blog post comment - the 'no' there looks pretty unequivocal already!

Comment: Yeah. But 'no' with a reason why carries more weight... Thanks again.

Comment: Is this still the case?  Community users cannot oAuth authenticate into Salesforce?

Comment: Community users can OAuth into Salesforce via web server or user-agent flows; just not username/password.

Comment: @metadaddy Are Partner Community User are able to use the SAML Bearer and JWT Flows?

Comment: Not sure - asking cmort over on Twitter

Comment: Word from on high: "JWT Bearer should work just fine for that"