# Logging partner community user in via oAuth from rest console

Tags: oauth2

I have set up a community and wish to access it via oAuth. Using the flows mentioned in the documentation I have no issues. Everything is good.
However I want to be able to login and then access my community via a REST console as this aids with debugging.
The profile of the user I want to log in is a Partner Community profile.
The problem that I have is that I do not have access to the security token for the partner community users.

Therefore if a send in the following request

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&password=<password>+<security_token>&username=<sys_admin_username>
```

it works but the following request

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&password=<password>&username=<partner_community_username>
```

fails and returns the following JSON

```
{"error_description":"authentication failure - Unknown exception: 1201","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. This link would imply that it is not possibe http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/should-oauth2-with-grant-type-password-work-for-high-volume-customer-portal?rq=1

Comment: Yes. Usename password flow looks to not be possible. User agent flow does work.