# OAuth2 Refresh Token Flow with Communities

Tags: community, oauth2, refresh-token

I'm trying to satisfy a requirement for providing an API for communities users, where they can log into Salesforce, retrieve some data, and provide that back to a client.  I have two questions around this that are related.

1) Can Salesforce Communities users log in with OAuth2 and the refresh token flow?

I found the following contrary point, but it is for username / password flow and not the refresh token flow: [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/should-oauth2-with-grant-type-password-work-for-high-volume-customer-portal](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/should-oauth2-with-grant-type-password-work-for-high-volume-customer-portal/19328#19328)

2) And a follow up to the above question:  Can the OAuth login page be branded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Communities users can use OAuth 2.0. Instead of `login.salesforce.com`, Use the Community URL as the prefix to the authorization URL - for example, `https://acme.force.com/customers/services/oauth2/authorize`. See the section **Configuring Authentication Flows with OAuth** in [Getting Started With Communities](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf).

Yes, the Community login page can be branded. See the section **Customizing Communities Login** in the same doc.

Comment: Clarified this as well.  Just a note that the branding applies only to the communities / site page and not, for instance, test.salesforce.com.  Makes complete sense, but an important distinction.