# SoapUI - Community User Login Setup

Tags: community, oauth2, rest

I want to setup some tests using the SoapUI Tool. The first part of my test involves getting a token for a community user.

Since the OAuth flow mechanisms are different for a community user, how can I setup a request in SoapUI to get a token for the community user from Salesforce?

The token request for a standard user looks like this.
[image: SoapUI]

If I change the username to a community user's username and the endpoint url to the community url, this throws an error about the invalid grant type. This is logical because all authentication flows are not supported by salesforce for community users.

So how can I get a token for a community user from SoapUI?

Comment: Username and password flow for oauth 2.0  is not possible for community users .Check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/should-oauth2-with-grant-type-password-work-for-high-volume-customer-portal?rq=1 .You may instead go with the other flows

Comment: Yes. What other flow will work with Soap UI ?

Comment: Use SOAP instead .Use enterprise WSDL and create a project there .Else why you want to use only SOAP ui to test ?you can use workbench to test your API

Comment: Using the workbench may not be an option for the community user's login. I plan to login as a community user and then run the APIs. I also need to do some load testing on the APIs.